# Creating new rows in a matrix, where the elements of these rows have to be different from previous rows(same row cannot occur twice) Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to generate a 3x2 matrix. Each row is generated using `randperm(3,2)`. This means each row is generated as a vector with 2 unique integers with values between 1 and 3.

The problem is that I want each new row to be different than all the previous. For example, if one row is [1 3] then no other row can be:

- [1 3], nor
- [3 1].

I tried checking the sum AND the multiplied value of each newly created row. (Using our example `1+3=4` and `1*3=3`)

My idea is that the multiplied value and the sum value of each new generated row is compared to the multiplied value and sum value of every other row that comes before it. If any of these values are the same (which means we will get a repetition), we keep generating a new row using `randperm(3,2)` until a completely new row is obtained.

My code checks each each row before one at a time, and "forgets" every other row that it previously checked. It does not take into consideration ALL the previous rows, instead it only iterates back one step at a time. I tried using something like parents(i:-1:1) instead of parents(i-k,1) etc but couldn't make it work.

**Question:** How can I do this comparison?

```
parents=randperm(3,2);
for i=2:3
parents=[parents; randperm(3,2)]

for k=1:i-1
    while prod(parents(i,:))==prod(parents(i-k,:)) && sum(parents(i,:))==sum(parents(i-k,:))
        parents(i,:)=randperm(3,2)
    end  
end
i=i+1;
end
```

Comment: There is a function either built-in or on the file exchange that will return all of the possible permutations of the elements of a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [this function](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn-v--n--k-), then use it as follows:

```
% generate all the possible permutations
p = permn(1:3,2);

% generate a random permutation of the indices and take the first three
r = randperm(size(p,1));
idx = r(1:3);

% take three random rows from the possible permutations using the indices
result = p(idx,:);
```

This way:

- you will never obtain a row identical to another one in your `result` matrix
- you won't be forced to use a "shuffle until condition is met" approach
- you have a reusable and flexible approach

Comment: Hi again and thanks alot for you answer. The code works but I forgot to mention something: apart from 2 rows not allowed to be equal, we cannot have a row containing 2 identical numbers. For example [3 3] is not allowed. I initially fixed this by using randperm in my code but as you saw, the other problem occured. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I think I solved it by just removing those rows, using p = permn(1:3,2)
b=[];
for i=1:length(p)
    if p(i,1)~=p(i,2); 
        b=[b;p(i,:)];
    end
end

However not sure if this is the most efficent solution

Comment: p_inv = p(:,1) == p(:,2); p(p_inv,:) = [];

Comment: Thank you. However it still seems like I am able to get things like [1 2] and [2 1] which is not allowed. No rows can be equal or "flipped" equal. It shows up more often now that we delete the rows [1 1], [2 2] and [3 3] from the permutations.

Comment: Aaah ok now it's clear. Let me edit the answer as soon as possible.